# Why do I get "TypeError a.outerHeight is not a function" when using for loop on elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I want to increase the performance of my script so I decided change `each()` method with a javascript `for` loop. Im getting a console error with `outerHeight()` method.

> jQuery.Deferred exception: a.outerHeight is not a function TypeError: a.outerHeight is not a function

How to solve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menuListElements = $('#mainMenuList').find("a.navigationLinks"), a;
    for (var i = 0; i < menuListElements.length; ++i) {
        a = menuListElements[i];
        if (a.outerHeight() > 25) {
            a.css({'color': "green"});
        } else a.css({'color': "black"});
    }
});
```

```css
#mainMenuList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: center;
}

#mainMenuList a {
    min-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainMenuList">
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 3 with more text</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 5 with more text</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 6 with more text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `a` becomes an `HTMLElement`, not a jQuery object, so you can't use jQuery methods on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `a` variable holds an *HTML* element. You should create a `jquery` object using

```
 a = $(menuListElements[i]);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menuListElements = $('#mainMenuList').find("a.navigationLinks"), a;
    for (var i = 0; i < menuListElements.length; i++) {
        a = $(menuListElements[i]);
        if (a.outerHeight() > 30) {
            a.css({'color': "green"});
        } else a.css({'color': "black"});
    }
});
```

```css
#mainMenuList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: center;
}

#mainMenuList a {
    min-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainMenuList">
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 3 with more text</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 5 with more text</a>
  <a href="#" class="navigationLinks">Link 6 with more text</a>
</div>
```